# `relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `stderr@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC`

Tags: c++, cmake

From looking around, basically, I need to set `POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE` to `ON` in the cmake build recipe file. But, it is turned on. So, any other help will be greatly appreciated.

The repo I am trying to build is : https://github.com/febiosoftware/FEBio

I checked the CMake file (line 178) in the repo. I am not adding the entire CMakeLists file because it is massive and because it is not my project and I am not good enough to create a minimum viable example. Could it be because of the OS? I am using Pop OS. I have also updated my compiler, but still it is not helping.

Comment: "From looking around, basically, I need to set POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE to ON in the cmake build recipe file." - No, you got it wrong. It is NOT the project which should be built with `-fPIC` enabled. It is the **library**, against which the project is **linked**, should be built with that option. Your question post doesn't contain the name of the library, so the most we can is to point you to the existed question on that topic.